# How to check if Firebase Message Service is in a boot completed state?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications using FCM. When the onMessageReceived is called in the service, I send the data to fragment via broadcastreceiver to add an item in the recyclerview. But because I have enabled directBootAware in the Manifest, The receiver is sending empty data to a non-existent fragment, when there is a notification sent just when the device has turned on. And due to this, When I open the app it crashes. So is there a way to know if the service is called immediately after boot completed? Something like this? :

```
\\Pseudo Code
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        if(inDirectBootMode()) {
            justSendNotification();
         } else {
            sendNotificationAndSendItemsToRecyclerview();
         }
}
```

Hope you'll help. Regards.

Comment: Can't you just check the data content ? if it is empty, you just don't do anything

Comment: No I need to send the notification. I do check if it is empty. If it is not empty, a notification is send and the notification is send to a recyclerview.

Comment: IMO it's a bad idea to for code like this that's not attached to a UI to try to send data directly to some view.  You should instead have some mechanism for the UI to subscribe to updates generated by this code and respond accordingly.  A LIveData, for example.

Comment: But the fragment is always visible to the user. So is broadcast receivers a bad thing?

Comment: I am not sending anything to the ui . I am just broadcasting the data from fcm and the fragment will fetch it if it is visible.